# is it idiomatic to say "speak English no well" & "speak English no good"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

> No (adv): used before adjectives and adverbs to mean ‘not’ ([source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/no_4))
>
> She's feeling no better this morning.
>
> Reply by no later than 21 July.
>
> good (adv): (especially North American English, informal) well
>   ([source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/good_3))
>
> ‘How's it going?’ ‘Pretty good.’
>
> (non-standard) Now, you listen to me good!

is it idiomatic to say "**speak English no well**" & "**speak English no good**"?

Comment: No, it is not idiomatic to use **no** with adverbs.  You would use **not** instead.

Answer (score 3):

For your example phrase

> speak English **not** well

would be a better choice, however, more idiomatic would be

> **not** speak English **well**
>
> He does **not** speak English **well**.

using "**well**" *(adverb)* with *speak* *(verb)* instead of "**good**" *(adjective)*

> He speaks English **well**.
>   He is **well** spoken.

You could also say

> His English is **no good**.
>   His English is **good**.

Comment: What about "**He is no good at English**"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct "**no good**" is the *predicate adjective*, though "He is **not good** at English" is also used.  "He is **not good** at English, he neither writes nor speaks it **well**."

Comment: No native English speaker would ever use the phrase _"speak English not well."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Agreed though the fact that the phrase is out of context makes it tricky. "I speak English. Not well, but I do." is idiomatic in spoken English though it doesn't have the meaning the OP intended. I'm wondering if there is a way to fix the phrase. When I read "not speak English well" it also seemed to me unidiomatic. Yet obviously "He does not speak English well," is perfectly fine.